# visual studio code jquery suggestion

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get VSC to auto suggest various functions within jquery? does the main Jquery js file need to be linked to the software somehow?

As an example I started typing this

```
$('#test').app
```

and it suggests `append`?

Comment: @charlietfl - Really not helpful, especially considering a lot of people will find this question in Google, just like I did.

Comment: exactly! I googled it and came here :) You can presume that someone asks a question on StackOverflow if they can't find a direct answer online (or perhaps don't understand - which would be very plausible since VS Code docs are sorely lacking)

Answer (score 16):

Try using `$` in a .js file. If you move your cursor near the warning, a light-bulb will appear. Either with `Ctrl+.` or by clicking on it, a code action will be proposed that will download and add a /// reference to jquery.d.ts that will give you all the nice IntelliSense for jQuery

[image: Code action on $]

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. When I click the action to "add a /// reference" nothing seems to happen.

Comment: @Tariq: do you work in a project or just a single file? I just opened a single file; this feature only seems to work with projects.

Comment: @Tariq: Also, VSCode cannot download the typings on your behalf if you're behind a proxy... It's a bug being worked on...

Comment: @nyn3x I didn't opened a project rather I have a static html page on which I am using jquery, I open these files as folder.

Comment: Weird. Me too. But  the reference was not inserted.

Comment: Note that the lightbulb will not appear if you are editing Javascript in an HTML file (within `<script>` tags) - you have to be editing a .js file.

Comment: Doesn't work for me either. Pressing ctrl+ zooms in on the page :) I am working in a .js file within a project. Do I need to download a jQuery definition first or something? (to get code completion?)

Answer (score 11):

### via npm (Node.js)

1. [Open the terminal](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal) (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>`</kbd>).
2. `npm install @types/jquery --save`.

### by hand (without Node.js installed)

1. Create `node_modules\@types\jquery\` folder structure within your project folder (if not exist). *
2. Get latest jQuery type definitions file from [GitHub](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/jquery/index.d.ts)

- Click "Raw".
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> (File > Save).

3. Save it to your `node_modules\@types\jquery\` folder as `index.d.ts`.
4. Done. You maybe need to reopen your *.js file or VS Code.

**Note**
You can also place the file anywhere else and name it differently. But if you do so, you will also need to reference it in every *.js file where you want to use jQuery code suggestions:

```
/// <reference path="jquery.d.ts" />
```

*the `node_modules` folder is recognized by VS Code for this because it *"comes with built-in support for JavaScript, TypeScript and Node.js"*, but to go the way of first solution you have to install [Node.js runtime](https://nodejs.org/en/).